# OXM: Mapping variable element names

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, moxy, oxm

From a legacy free-style web service, I'm receiving data of the following kind:

```
<settings>
    <key1>value1</key1>
    <key2>value2</key2>
    ...
    <keyN>valueN</keyN>
</settings>
```

The element names `key1, key2, ...` are *not* known beforehand and could be any identifier, so this is not easily expressible in XSD except by `any` and not directly mappable in JAXB.

Is it possible, using any JAXB extension, to somehow map this to

```
public class Settings {
    private List<Property> properties;
}

public Property {
    private String key;
    private String value;
}
```

I tried MOXy's `@XPath`, but could not find a suitable XPath expression.

Any solution is welcome, it doesn't have to be MOXy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MOXy we offer this mapping through the `@XmlVariableNode` extension:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/06/moxys-xmlvariablenode-json-schema.html